# Appending values in to a new array using JS

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to build a form (more for personal learning) using HTML, JS and local storage to:

1. Take inputs from user
2. Display the inputs from the user
3. Store the data in local storage
4. Give an option to the user to strike through an item or strike through everything

**Questions:**

- The local storage always is storing the latest value entered and not the entire array. For some reason the push array is not appending all the values. What am i missing?
- The strike through works for all at once but not for each option. What's the way to go about it for each option?

```js
function display(){
      var master_list = [];
      var data = document.getElementById('to_do').value;
      master_list.push(data);
      document.getElementById('form_data').innerHTML += "<li>"+ data +"</li>";
      console.log("data is "+ data);
      console.log("master list is "+ master_list);
      // storeData(master_list);
    }
    
    function remove(){
      var list = document.getElementById('form_data').innerText;
      // console.log("the data is " + list);
      document.getElementById('form_data').innerHTML = list.strike();
    
    }
    
    function storeData(master_list){
      localStorage.setItem("master_list", JSON.stringify(master_list));
    
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>The To-do Application</title>
        <script src="to_do_app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <h1>Welcome to the To-Do application</h1>
        <label>Enter your to-do item: </label>
        <input type="text" id="to_do" placeholder="eg: groceries">
        <button onclick=display()> Add </button>
        <h3>Added Items are:</h3>
        <div id="form_data"></div>
        <br>
        <button onclick=remove()> Clear All </button>
        <!-- <h6>Note: To remove please click on the item</h6> -->
      </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Please, ask just one question per post. Also note that `strike()` has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/strike).

Comment: Move your `master_list` outside your `display()` function as a global variable. RIght now you are resetting your list every time, which explains why only an array with one entry is stored inside your `localStorage`.

Comment: declare your master_list as a global variable and outside the display function.

Comment: Don't declare a global variable..global variables should be avoided. Instead of newing up your array you need to load it from [local storage `var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('master_list);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: Also see [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript) if you put these two questions together it should give you everything you need to fix this

Comment: please avoid global variables, especially if you don't set them to undefined or null so that they will be garbage collected. if you always update a global variable without nullifying it , it will definitely lead to memory leak

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if `master_list` item already exists in localStorage using `localStorage.getItem` ( it will acutally return null if there the requested item does not exists)

```
const storeData= master_list => {
    let item = localStorage.getItem("master_list");
    if ( ! item ) {
        localStorage.setItem("master_list", master_list);
        return;
    }
    item = JSON.parse("master_list");
    item.concat(master_list); // or master_list.concat(item) depending on your needs
    localStorage.setItem("master_list", item);
};
```